# how to solve the integral of square root of polynomial

Tags: integration, polynomials, definite-integrals, exponential-function, radicals

I would like to learn how to evaluate the following integral. I have checked the table of integrals and could not manage to solve it. Can you please help me?

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{\left(1- \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\right)}  e^{ ({-\frac{x}{c}})} dx$

Comment: I do not believe this integral has an elementary antiderivative or closed form solution.

Comment: @PeterForeman. I guess that, for large $c$, $I(c)\sim c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Peter Foreman commented, do not expect too much for an antiderivative (even using special functions) or a closed form result.

What we can notice is that
$$I(c)=\int_0^\infty\sqrt{1- \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}}e^{ {-\frac{x}{c}}}\,dx <\int_0^\infty e^{ {-\frac{x}{c}}}\,dx=c$$

The only solution left is numerical integration. Trying 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c & I(c) \\
 1 & 0.743781495 \\
 10 & 9.532405111 \\
 100 & 99.44992339 \\
 1000 & 999.4324691 \\
 10000 & 9999.429709 \\
 100000 & 99999.42916 
\end{array}
\right)$$ which seems to show that, for large values of $c$
$$I(c) \sim c - 0.57$$ is a rather good approximation.

Comment: If `c->Infinity` then: $$I (c) = c - \frac {\pi} {2} + 1 $$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk. How did you get it ? I am really interested by a rigorous asymptotics. Thanks for telling. Cheers :-)

Comment: I used CAS with numerics to estimate the constant,and this website:http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html and I don't have 
evidence that is true :P